# Why is my response data failing to load raw, but with any additional string echoed before, it load perfectly?

Tags: javascript, php

I have this API where I send an id and it returns the data for it.

Using the Postman app, it works perfectly, and if I type the URL directly to the browser, it returns the appropriate error object that I coded, but when I fetch it in JavaScript, in the network tab I can see all my headers correctly, the id appears in the form-data format but I get the message:

> **"response failed to load"** .

Only if I echo in my PHP API some string before the actual response, I can see the response in the network tab, but with the additional string in front.

I am using **application/json** in my headers.

This won't load:

```
echo json_encode($returnInfo);
```

This will:

```
echo "string" . json_encode($returnInfo);
```

It is not my first time coding this kind of stuff, but I'm not sure how to approach this error.

What might I be doing wrong?

**Screenshots**

[image: Headers of the request]

[image: Preview of the response without echoing a string in front]

[image: Preview of the response echoing a string in front]

Comment: What exactly shows up in the browser "Network" tool for the HTTP request?

Comment: Hi @Pointy I just added some screenshots. Thanks for the quick response.

Comment: Ok so, if I set the header to accept text/html, it works, but I still don't understand why it would work when I was sending the JSON object with the string in front when it was set to accept JSON format.

Comment: This is indeed a bit mysterious. Can you try using Fiddler to inspect the _exact_ request and response contents in the two cases? It's possible some Chrome extension or something like that is interfering.

Comment: And in the devtools also check if there are any warnings in the console tab related to your request.